# Laravel how to access, in a view, a value passed by a controller, but inside a script section

Tags: ajax, laravel

From a request handler I pass a parameter to a request view:

```
public function sol_solicitante(Request $request, $param){
    return view('solicitante.solicitudes', compact('param'));
}
```

The view that the controller invokes is:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title','Buzón Solicitudes')

@section('css')
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.6/css/responsive.bootstrap4.min.css">
@endsection

@section('content')
    <div class="container mt-4">  
        <div>
            <h2>Buzón De Solicitudes</h2>  
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                
                <!--
                    <a href="crear">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success float-right">Crear Solicitud</button>
                    </a>
                </h2>
                -->
                <table class="table table-hover" id="buzonsolicitudes">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Id</th>
                            <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
                            <th scope="col">Estado</th>
                            <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>                    
                </table>            
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection

@section('js')
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>    
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.6/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.6/js/responsive.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <script>   
    
        $('#buzonsolicitudes').DataTable({
            "ajax": "{{ route('datatable.sol_solicitante',['param' => '1'])}}",
            "columns":[
                {data:'id'},
                {data:'nombre'},
                {data:'estadologico'},
                {data:'btn'}
            ],
            responsive: true,
            autoWidth: false,
            "language": {
                "lengthMenu": "Mostrar " + 
                                `<select class="custom-select" custom-select-sm form-control form-control-sm>
                                    <option value='10'>10</option>
                                    <option value='25'>25</option>
                                    <option value='50'>50</option>
                                    <option value='100'>100</option>
                                    <option value='-1'>Todos</option>
                                </select>` +
                                " registros por página",            
                "zeroRecords": "Nada encontrado - disculpa",
                "info": "Mostrando página _PAGE_ de _PAGES_",
                "infoEmpty": "Ningún registro disponible",
                "infoFiltered": "(filtrado de _MAX_ registros totales)",
                'search':'Buscar',
                'paginate':{
                    'next':'siguiente',
                    'previous':'anterior'
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
@endsection
```

What I don't know is how to access, in the view, the parameter sent by the controller, since I must pass it as a parameter to the Ajax call; Something like:

```
<script>   
    var p= param

    $('#buzonsolicitudes').DataTable({
        "ajax": "{{ route('datatable.sol_solicitante',['param' => p])}}",
```

This that I put does not work and checking I do not find how it should be.

I appreciate all help, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php codes are processed on server. the blade compiles all variables before page loads. look you are already using route helper. just pass the variable to the helper as you do in other places.

```
"ajax": "{{ route('datatable.sol_solicitante', ['param' => $param]) }}"
```

this will generate the route as you defined on your web.php file like `mysite.com/datatable/sol_solicitante/param_value`

Comment: I already have the web routes file.

Route::get('datatables/sol_solicitante/{param}','DatatableController@sol_solicitante')->name('datatable.sol_solicitante');

what i dont know is how inside view script i access parameter value passed from controller. I don't know if it's something like. From the controller I pass the variable param, but I don't know what is the syntax of the instruction to access its value in the view:

<script> var p= {{$param}} or var p='{{param}}'   ????

Well, that way I can pass that variable to the path that invokes ajax

Comment: you don't have to set the php variable to a js variable..you can use it directly as i answered. however if you want to set this to a js variable you can do both `var p= {{ $param }}` or `var p='{{ $param }}'`

Answer (score 0):

You should create a script in blade file. In that script, you add init some variables with value from controller

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your script

```
 var data ={!! $data->id !!};  //data->id is variable send by controller
```

you can directly access this variable in script

Try this hope it works

Comment: <script>   
        var param ={!! $param !!};
    
        $('#buzonsolicitudes').DataTable({
            "ajax": "{{ route('datatable.sol_solicitante',['param' => param])}}",
            "columns":[
                {data:'id'},

Comment: ErrorException
Use of undefined constant param - assumed 'param' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) (View: D:\laragon\www\siged\resources\views\solicitante\solicitudes.blade.php)

Comment: Are you getting data in "param"  in script

Comment: why are you mixing php and js?? they are completely different.

Comment: @zahidhasanemon as per question asked this solution is working fine

Comment: sorry. i mean the op actually. he is mixing php and js and that won't work.

Comment: I did a test. In the controller $ param = 1 and I printed it in the laravel log "([2020-12-14 05:28:22] local.INFO: 1)". 
then I printed the value of the parameter in the view and it printed 1 "(<p>{{$param}}</p>)". inside the script, print 1. " <script>   
        var param ={!! $param !!}
        console.log(param) ", the error arises when that variable is placed in the path that invokes Ajax "{{ route('datatable.sol_solicitante',['param' => param]) }}" .  so how should the param variable go there

Comment: as i said you are mixing php and js here. `{{ route('datatable.sol_solicitante',['param' => param]) }}` is php code so just put the php variable directly there. like  `{{ route('datatable.sol_solicitante',['param' => $param]) }}`

Comment: The way it is implemented works, if what I want to do is be able to pass a parameter to the view so that it has to be passed to the datatable controller and there I develop the decision logic based on the value of the parameter. In the end I understand that it must be a simple error, since I am misplacing the syntax of the param variable in the path that Ajax invokes

Comment: @JuncoFuerte try  like this to append the  id or pass the param variable     
var url = "{{URL('userData/'.$userData->id)}}";

Comment: @zahidhasanemon its only variable name its not mixing anything

Comment: your parameter will be passed as you designed. you are just using php to generate the url for the ajax url. nothing more. you have to understand what is serverside and client side code and how to use them. just as i answered try with that and your code will work as expected.

Comment: @RushikeshGanesh it's mixing obviously. `{{ route('datatable.sol_solicitante',['param' => param]) }}` is php code where he used `param` which is a js variable. how come they will work??

Comment: Dear @zahid hasan emon, I greatly appreciate your help and explanation. I did what you told me to do and it worked correctly. Thank you very much for your kindness and support.

Comment: @zahidhasanemon answer the question if i am wrong  , i am not here for any debate i want to solve someones problem nothing else

Comment: Dear @Rushikesh Ganesh, I appreciate your time and help by making your comments to help me. Thank you very much.

Comment: hey man we are here to help each other. not to debate. i am just explaining things.

Comment: I thank you both for your time, you helped me a lot to solve the problem and better understand how this works. Goodnight.